# SPHINX SE DOUBTS

Tags: sphinx

What differences are there between group by and group sort?

How to implement set select in sphinx SE?

Comment: Please edit your question to give it a more meaningful title. Questions on stack overflow are intended to be of long term benefit to everyone, and be searchable and easy to find. Your question title is meaningless as written.

Answer (score 0):

groupby: what function and attribute to use for grouping

groupsort: what order to retrieve the groups in.

use 'select'. But be careful that your sphinxSE table has the right columns to use the output

(btw, its sphinxSE not "sphinx SE")

Comment: while executing following query i am getting following error. I have declared fname as a FIELD.

SELECT FNAME FROM indexname WHERE query=';select=FNAME+1*2 as myexpr;';
ERROR 1430 (HY000): There was a problem processing the query on the foreign data source. Data source error: unknown parameter 'select'

Comment: Your version of sphinx might be too old. - ie before select was added to sphinxSE. Also you using it wrong anyway, with that 'select' would need SELECT myexpr FROM ... . The 'select' adds it to the data searchd sends sphinxSE, then sphinxSE will include it as a column - as long as it was defined as column when you created the virtual table.